# Data property with value equal to number of individuals in a class?

Tags: ontology, protege

Is possible to define a data property of a class as the number of individuals of another class, and this number is computed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality for counting already available, far as I know.

It could be implemented for asserted axioms, but I don't think it can be guaranteed to work reliably. The open world assumption and the default non unique name assumption mean that it's impossible to say if there are unknown individuals or if any of the known individuals are sameAs each other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer